# Not understanding what is being passed into method

Tags: java, compareto

So I've been given pre-written code and I have to fill in the `comepareTo` function. It needs to compare strings and sort them by length but I'm not sure what is being passed in the method.

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

 public class testString implements Comparable<testString> {
  String tempStr;

 public testString(String str) {
    tempStr = str;
 }

 public String toString() {
   return tempStr;
 }

 public int compareTo(testString Str2) {

  return 0;
 }


 String [] list = {"dog", "cat", "lion", "python", "giraffe", "emu"};
 testString [] list2 = new testString[list.length];
 for (int i=0; i<list2.length; i++) {
   list2[i] = new testString(list[i]);
 }
```

I'm not exactly sure what the type is that is being passed into the `compareTo` function (Str2).
I thought it would be a list and I could run through it with a for loop, but that's giving me errors if I try Str2[1].

Answer (score 0):

Str2 parameter is an object of type testString (your defined class). 
The method is used to compare the current object with the one received as parameter. To make sense such a comparison the objects must be of the same type.

check also the API documentation for Comparable interface. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

The method compareTo is part of this interface.

In your case, the easiest implementation would be:
return this.tempStr.compareTo(Str2.tempStr);

of course, Str2 must not be null :)

Answer (score 0):

What would you create an object if you just want to store a string in the first place ?

Anyway you just need to implement your compare method by substracting the length of your tempStr value with the length of the parameter. In the end you just need to return the result.

Comment: Ah ok, I was confused by how I was getting the first string, but its stored in temp string. I ended up getting it so it returns, 1,0,or-1. Thanks.